# ES 7.7 failed to join a cluster because of time-out

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build ElasticSearch cluster but it cause an error.

Log for master node

```
[2020-06-23T16:33:47,361][WARN ][o.e.c.c.Coordinator      ] [kn-log-01] failed to validate incoming join request from node [{kn-log-02}{tuCA1_YARK-HkHyzbpG4Nw}{0yZHEJGAQpKgWw336U2vDQ}{127.0.0.2}{127.0.0.2:9300}{dilrt}{ml.machine_memory=134888939520, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [kn-log-02][127.0.0.2:9300][internal:cluster/coordination/join/validate] request_id [88] timed out after [59835ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:1041) [elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:633) [elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
```

Log for data node to join

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [kn-log-01][127.0.0.1:9300][internal:cluster/coordination/join]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failure when sending a validation request to node
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.Coordinator$2.onFailure(Coordinator.java:514) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1139) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1139) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$8.run(TransportService.java:1001) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:633) ~[elasticsearch-7.7.0.jar:7.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [kn-log-02][127.0.0.2:9300][internal:cluster/coordination/join/validate] disconnected
[2020-06-23T16:41:47,433][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [kn-log-02] master not discovered yet: have discovered [{kn-log-02}{tuCA1_YARK-HkHyzbpG4Nw}{0yZHEJGAQpKgWw336U2vDQ}{127.0.0.2}{127.0.0.2:9300}{dilrt}{ml.machine_memory=134888939520, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9300, 127.0.0.3:9300, 127.0.0.4:9300] from hosts providers and [] from last-known cluster state; node term 1, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
[2020-06-23T16:41:57,434][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [kn-log-02] master not discovered yet: have discovered [{kn-log-02}{tuCA1_YARK-HkHyzbpG4Nw}{0yZHEJGAQpKgWw336U2vDQ}{127.0.0.2}{127.0.0.2:9300}{dilrt}{ml.machine_memory=134888939520, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9300, 127.0.0.3:9300, 127.0.0.4:9300] from hosts providers and [] from last-known cluster state; node term 1, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
```

It saying time-out error and I don't know how to solve it. It doesn't work now but yesterday did. I didn't change any settings about ElasticSearch (maybe).

What I did already:

- Checking firewalld settings about 9200, 9300 port again.
- Rebooting all machines.
- Wipe ElasticSearch data folders and restart services.

EDIT

elasticsearch.yml for master node (comments were omitted)

```yaml
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: kn-log-01
path.data: /data/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2", "127.0.0.3", "127.0.0.4"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["kn-log-01"]
node.master: true
node.data: true
```

elasticsearch.yml for data node

```yaml
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: kn-log-02
path.data: /data/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2", "127.0.0.3", "127.0.0.4"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["kn-log-01"]
node.master: false
node.data: true
```

`ensure both instances are up and running`

```
$  curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200
{
  "name" : "kn-log-01",
  "cluster_name" : "mycluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "jN-0FJwDRZqlAtQ6LpXwug",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.7.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "81a1e9eda8e6183f5237786246f6dced26a10eaf",
    "build_date" : "2020-05-12T02:01:37.602180Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
$ curl -XGET 127.0.0.2:9200
{
  "name" : "kn-log-02",
  "cluster_name" : "mycluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.7.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "81a1e9eda8e6183f5237786246f6dced26a10eaf",
    "build_date" : "2020-05-12T02:01:37.602180Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
$ curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/nodes?v
ip             heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
127.0.0.1           15           2   0    0.01    0.03     0.05 dilmrt    *      kn-log-01
```

Comment: Can you add Elasticsearch.yaml files and ensure both instances are up and running

Comment: @Gibbs Yes I did that.

Comment: @JeongHansol how come both the nodes are up and showing the same name `cluster_name` so these logs are before the issue? and only for data node log seems to be the issue as its an exception but is it causing data node to stop?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja No. All logs are after the issue. Data node trying to connect the master node infinitely but doesn't hang. (logging error messages every minutes) It isn't a part of the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved finally. An issue was caused by physical network problem.

MTU of the ethernet card was configured with value that hardware do not support. So I fix it then now it works.